# Find and separate max elements in a directory with diferent file names on it

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, max

I'm trying to find the maximum elements in a directory but that directory has different file names on it, if I make a list and use the `max()` Function ,I only get one result (the max one obviously) , but how can I separate the files before use max so I can get the max elements separately, or there is a method or function that do that?
Thanks.

```
example_directory_list = ['CM_30_00.v01', 'CM_30_00.v02', 'CM_30_00.v03', 'CM_30_00_house.v01','CM_30_00_house.v02', 'CM_30_00_house.v03', 'CM_30_01.v01', 'CM_30_00', 'CM_30_01']

print max (example_directory_list )

result ['CM_30_00.v03','CM_30_00_house.v03', 'CM_30_01.v01']
```

Comment: `example_directory_list ` is a list if strings. what is the logic of finding max?

Comment: Please add the desired result to your question.

Comment: I can transform the list to a string, but how can I get only the elements with the max number at the end? Im trying not use regex.

Comment: How you reached to the expected result, what is the logic inside `max` function?

Comment: `CM_30_01.v01` does not have max number at end

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear. It seems the file extension is a version number, and you want to get the filename of the highest version for each different file.

In the code below, I ignore files with no extensions.

It is by no means robust. I don't even bother extracting the version number as an `int`. It compares the file extensions as `str`.

It works by looping through all the filenames, separating the filename and extension, compares the extension with the highest version seen so far (or "v00" if it hasn't yet come across the same filename), and updates the `dict` if necessary. Finally, it reconstructs the highest filenames and stores them in the `results` `list`.

```py
example_directory_list = ['CM_30_00.v01', 
                          'CM_30_00.v02', 
                          'CM_30_00.v03', 
                          'CM_30_00_house.v01', 
                          'CM_30_00_house.v02', 
                          'CM_30_00_house.v03', 
                          'CM_30_01.v01', 
                          'CM_30_00', 
                          'CM_30_01', ]

files = {}

for filename in example_directory_list:
    dot_index = filename.rfind(".")
    if dot_index == -1:
        continue
    name_without_extension = filename[:dot_index]
    extension = filename[dot_index+1:]
    
    highest_version = files.get(name_without_extension, "v00")
    if extension > highest_version:
        files[name_without_extension] = extension

results = [f"{filename}.{extension}" for filename, extension in files.items()]

print(results)
```

Output:

```
['CM_30_00.v03', 'CM_30_00_house.v03', 'CM_30_01.v01']
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. Yes that makes the trick, I was a little bit loss because I was triying to do it just with one function (like max()), I was thinking like: 'theres gonna be a kind of python's easy filter function' . But I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I made this little change to work in python 2.

```
results =[]
for filename, extension in files.items():
    result = ("{filename}.{extension}".format(**locals()))
    results.append(result)
```

Comment: That's a fascinating use of `format()` and `**locals()`! This one-liner would work in Python 2, as well: `results = ["{}.{}".format(filename, extension) for filename, extension in files.items()]`